# writing a method that takes an array of strings and orders the strings by number of vowels from least to greatest, and keeps the alphabetical order

Tags: java

The goal of this program is to change the array of strings given to make the array show the string with the least amount of vowels to the greatest while having it in alphabetical order. The output should look like this :

```
[hello, Apple, hat, cat, Banana, AAA]
[cat, hat, Apple, hello, AAA, Banana]
```

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = {"hello", "apple", "hat", "cat", "Banana", "AAA"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
    orderByVowels(strings);
}

public static void orderByVowels(String[] order) {
    for(int i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
        for(int j = i+1; j < order.length; j++) {
            if(order[i].compareTo(order[j]) > 0) {
                String tppp = order[i];
                order[i] = order[j];
                order[j] = tppp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (String order1 : order) {
        System.out.print(order1 + " ");
    }
}
```

My problem is the output puts the order of the strings in the right order but its not in an array. How can I put the new string order into an array and print it out to be like the output I showed above?

Comment: Don't loop through the array at the end. You can just print the array itself.

Comment: Side note: don't apologize for messy formatting. Instead: don't format messy! Messy code makes it hard to read and understand. You want us to help; so you show some more respect and take at least the time to make that easy for us. Besides: 50% of good programming ... boils down to discipline. Better start practicing that from day 1.

Comment: @takendarkk Nonsense. When one does println(someArray) ... it will NOT print the array content; but the reference that the array represents. Arrays are NOT ArrayLists (those would print themselves nicely).

Comment: @Jägermeister ill take that in consideration only because of your name ;)

Comment: eclipse ctrl+shift+f. No one needs to format code manually anymore :-)

Comment: Ok, I wasn't explicit enough. Use `Arrays.toString()`.

Comment: @Leo is it bad that I am using netbeans? :o

Comment: netbeans probably has something similar. all IDEs usually have

Comment: @Leo Well, some beginners still prefer to learn programming with java the oldschool way; using some stupid text editor, and command line tools. And surprisingly, that is a pretty good strategy for beginners; as there is a lot of value in understanding what eclipse is actually doing for you. There are enough folks out there who just know how to click buttons and that are helplessly lost when their IDE stops working.

Comment: No, it's bad that you still haven't edited your post and posted improved formatted code. Look up how to do this with NetBeans.

Comment: @leo ahh true, ill try to find it.

Comment: do you need to use only 1 array or can you use a second array?

Comment: @Leo i can have two arrays, like the original one and then the new one that sets the order correctly.

Comment: Another side note: try to find better names for your variables. A name should say "what it is". tppp ... what's that for example?!

Comment: @Jägermeister Java is so verbose that I really prefer to use an IDE always. Of course, there are some very rare situations where we have to write using vi but fortunately this is very very rare :-)

Comment: @Progamminnoob 2 arrays is less efficient, but I think the code is clearer. And early optimization is the root of all evil, specially when people are learning to code :-)

Comment: @Leo Of course, i do my work with eclipse. But initially, to really understand what the compiler does; and how classpath and JARs and all of that *work* ... there is some merit in doing the heavy lifting yourself; without much tooling.

Comment: So delete the loop and print it out in the main? that's all I need to do? @Leo jagermesiter takendarkk

Comment: This code does NOT output in the correct order.

Comment: How important is it to consider unicode vowels besides the obvious 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', and 'u'? (E.g. vowels with diacritical marks) Not everything is ASCII these days...

Comment: And what about lower case vs. upper? Does "E" sort before "a"? (Hint: it will if you use `String.compareTo()` for the alphabetical order part.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first need to write a method to calculate vowel count in a string. Once that is done, we need to use both vowel count and string comparison in sorting logic. Below example should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = { "hello", "apple", "hat", "cat", "Banana", "AAA" };
    // Displaying the initial array..
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
    orderByVowels(strings);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
}

public static void orderByVowels(String[] order) {

    for (int i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < order.length; j++) {
            int countI = getVowelCount(order[i]);
            int countJ = getVowelCount(order[j]);
            if(countI > countJ
                    || (countI == countJ && order[i].compareTo(order[j]) > 0)){
                String tppp = order[i];
                order[i] = order[j];
                order[j] = tppp;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static int getVowelCount(String input){
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
        char c =input.toLowerCase().charAt(j);
        if(c=='a')
            count++;
        else if(c=='e')
            count++;
        else if(c=='i')
            count++;
        else if(c=='o')
            count++;
        else if(c=='u')
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the compareTo() for alphabetical should work off all lower (or all upper) case? As it stands, "BBBaaa" sorts before "Banana".

Answer (score 0):

As of late, I've been a fan of Guava's `Ordering` class.  If you're not adverse to using Lists and a library from Google, it has exactly what you're looking for with its `Ordering.compound(secondaryComparator)` method, which uses a secondaryComparator in the event of a tie in the first comparator.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.collect.Ordering;
import com.google.common.primitives.Ints;

public class SortStringArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] testArray = 
            {"hello", "Apple", "hat", "cat", "Banana", "AAA"};
        final List<String> testList = Arrays.asList(testArray);

        final Ordering<String> byNumVowels = new Ordering<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String left, String right) {
                return Ints.compare(vowelCount(left), vowelCount(right));
            }

            private int vowelCount(final String str) {
                if (str == null) {
                    return 0;
                }

                int count = 0;
                final String strLowercase = str.toLowerCase();
                for (int i = 0; i < strLowercase.length(); i++) {
                    final char c = strLowercase.charAt(i);
                    if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u') {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                return count;
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(testList, byNumVowels.compound(Ordering.natural()));
        System.out.print(testList);
    }
}
```

The magic happens here:

```
Collections.sort(testList, byNumVowels.compound(Ordering.natural()));
```

where the comparator you define is checked against first, and in the event of a tie, uses the natural ordering (lexicographical).

Note: The comparator returned by Ordering.natural() will throw a null pointer exception if it is given a null String.  Ordering provides a easy readable way to handle this as well:

```
Collections.sort(testList, byNumVowels.nullsFirst().compound(Ordering.natural()));
```